# Таблица умножения на java! Помогите найти и исправить ошибку

Tags: java, ооп

Создал 2 файла (т.к. нужно учить и осваивать ООП).
Компилятор ругается на ошибку в 12й строке в двух файлах.

**UPD:** `int tablex[] на ArrayList tablex = new ArrayList();`

Компилятор пишет ошибку в **main.java**:

```
Error:(16, 31) java: incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to java.util.ArrayList
Error:(18, 32) java: bad operand types for binary operator '>'
  first type:  java.util.ArrayList
  second type: int
Error:(19, 62) java: array required, but java.util.ArrayList found
Error:(19, 84) java: array required, but java.util.ArrayList found
```

Компилятор пишет ошибку в **main.java**:

```
Error:(17, 19) java: not a statement
Error:(17, 21) java: ';' expected
```

---

**a2.java**:

```
package table;

public class a2 {
    public static int[] create(int x) {
        int[] tablex = new int[9];
        for (int i = 1; i<10; i++) {
            tablex[i] = x * i;
            tablex[i+1] = i; //12 строка
        }
        return tablex;
    }
}
```

---

**UPD:** **main.java**:

```
package table;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import static java.lang.reflect.Array.getLength;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //ArrayList tablex = new ArrayList();
        int tablex[] = null;
        a2 aa = new a2();
        for (int i = 2; i < 9; i++) {
            tablex[] =aa.create(i);//17 строка
            ArrayList tablex = new ArrayList();
            int first_int = i;
            for (i = 0; tablex > i; i++) {
                System.out.println(first_int + " * " + tablex[i + 1] + " = " + tablex[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Было бы не плохо и ошибку написать, конечно. Могу предположить, что ошибка в том, что вы ссылаетесь на несуществующую ячейку в массиве

Comment: Удалите старый код, он не представляет интереса. Компилятор Вам указал на 4 ошибки, а не на одну. Ваша функция create возвращает массив int, вы же пытаетесь это неявно привести к типу ArrayList, о чем Вам компилятор и сообщает. Таблица умножения - плохой пример для практики принципов ООП.

Comment: Вы присваете ArrayList-у ссылку на массив. for (i = 0; tablex > i; i++) - оператор > не применим к кооллекциям

Comment: Так же у вас в условии цикла в main ошибка, tablex - это массив , вы не можете проверять tablex > i

Answer (score 4):

```
int[] tablex = new int[9];
   for (int i = 1; i<10; i++){
       tablex[i] = x * i;
       tablex[i+1] = i; //12 строка
   }
```

У вас размер массива 9 , а вы в цикле начинаете с 1 и до 10 , индексы в массиве начинаются с 0 и до `length -1`. Когда вы захотите обратится к i+1 ,а текущее i = 10 , то вы выйдете за пределы массива. Смотрите внимательно на индексы.

Нельзя ArrayList конвертировать к типу int[]. Можно создать ArrayList на базе массива.